# Sistema de Download do banco de dados Erro about:blank#blocked

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Tenho o seguinte problema, no sistema que estou trabalhando temos uma opcao de download de archivo em pdf e excel, o sistema esta construido con React, React-Redux, Redux-Saga. Bom esse sistema de Download funcionava bem até que se teve que acrescentar um parametro, (money_type). Bom fiz isso, mas quando vou tentar fazer o Download me aparece erro muito estranho que nao consegui encontrar repostas.

O Select para a chamada da funcao.

```
      <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" variant="secondary" title="Descargar">
                                  <Dropdown.Item onClick={handlePDF}>Descargar PDF</Dropdown.Item>
                                  <Dropdown.Item onClick={handleExcel}>Descargar Excel</Dropdown.Item>
                                </DropdownButton>
                              </Col>
```

Essas sao a funcoes que estao sendo chamadas

```
const handlePDF = () => {
if(type === '1' || type === '4')
  showAccountingPDF({ data: `${uuid}/?society=${society}${date}&rule=${rule}`, type });
if(type === '2' || type === '3')
  showAccountingPDF({ data: `${uuid}/?society=${society}${date}&rule=${rule}&report_type=${typeFinancialSituation}`, type });
```

}

```
const handleExcel = () => {
if(type === '1' || type === '4')
  showAccountingExcel({ data: `${uuid}/?society=${society}${date}&rule=${rule}`, type });
if(type === '2' || type === '3')
  showAccountingExcel({ data: `${uuid}/?society=${society}${date}&rule=${rule}&report_type=${typeFinancialSituation}`, type });
```

}

Este é o saga que esta enviando o estado, acho eu.. Ja que nao tenho muito conhecimento em SAGAS

```
    function* showAccountingPDF({ payload }) {
  try {
    const { data, type, money } = payload
    const accessToken = cookieHandler().getAccessToken();
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    if(type === "1")
      link.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL}api/v1/modules/module/balance8columns/export/pdf/${data}&token=${accessToken}`;
    if(type === "2")
      link.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL}api/v1/modules/module/financial-situation/export/pdf/${data}&token=${accessToken}`;
    if(type === "3")
      link.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL}api/v1/modules/module/status-results/export/pdf/${data}&token=${accessToken}`;
    if(type === "4")
      link.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL}api/v1/modules/module/cashflow/export/pdf/${data}&token=${accessToken}`;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'report.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    yield;
  } catch (e) {
    // TODO: handle error
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

O erro que me aparece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a url que formula para o download do arquivo:
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/modules/module/financial-situation/export/pdf/bd3185d0-7c3f-4f04-bbb4-220bb0f93b5d/?end_month=12&end_year=2021&format=api&report_type=COMPARE&rule=IFRS&society=d1582e2b-0b72-4c83-a6a2-e3e73f6746d6&start_month=12&start_year=2022&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc0NjU0NTU1LCJqdGkiOiJiOTU4Mzc4MjE0Y2Q0YmI4OGMyMzczNTgxYzZhNTk4NiIsInVzZXJfdXVpZCI6ImE0M2Q2NjhjLWI0MDgtNDg0Yi1iNTVlLTcyYzAwYTQzYzM0NyJ9.Ix3facZt7N-JU5e0TkG6-emuzwqjayHpwF0Irk1iNz0&money_type=LOCAL

Bom, tudo isso estou tentando realizar localmente. Agredaço se vocês puderem me ajudar.

Answer (score -2):

solución de mi problema. Les cuento caso tenga un problema parecido al mio.

En la parte donde se crea la ruta y hace la descarga insert un /
Y entonces me encontro la ruta, y se me descargo el archivo.
`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL}/api/v1/modules/module/balance8columns/export/pdf/${data}&token=${accessToken}`

function* showAccountingPDF({ payload }) {
try {
const { data, type, money } = payload
const accessToken = cookieHandler().getAccessToken();
const link = document.createElement('a');
if(type === "1")
link.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL}api/v1/modules/module/balance8columns/export/pdf/${data}&token=${accessToken}`;
if(type === "2")
link.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL}api/v1/modules/module/financial-situation/export/pdf/${data}&token=${accessToken}`;
if(type === "3")
link.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL}api/v1/modules/module/status-results/export/pdf/${data}&token=${accessToken}`;
if(type === "4")
link.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_URL}api/v1/modules/module/cashflow/export/pdf/${data}&token=${accessToken}`;
link.setAttribute('download', 'report.pdf');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
yield;
} catch (e) {
// TODO: handle error
console.log(e);
}
}